# How to show scrollbar on a CalendarView?

Tags: android, xml, scroll, view, scrollbar

I have seen that in a ScrollView, to show always the scrollbar, adding ´android:fadeScrollbars="false"´ is enough, but that is not working in a CalendarView. How could I do it then?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any source code about scrollbar, maybe it doesn't have one.